# Rails simple format error when special character

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I am using a `simple_format tag` and when I use a ' it gives me an error but without it there is no error how do I fix this?

```
<%= simple_format(Bob's Text) %>
```

Comment: Pass a variable 
<%= simple_format(bobs_text) %>
or a string
<%= simple_format("Bob's Text") %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing your text as a string. Try this instead:

```
<%= simple_format("Bob's Text") %>
```

Comment: How would you do this if you are getting a value from a database? Would you do 'vaule_from_db' to make it a string?

Comment: The value from the DB should be a variable. You won't need quotes for that:

e.g. <%= simple_format(user.name) %>